# how to create a custom control inherit from form.control class

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

as title said, i want to create a custom control from control class.
but it doesn't display on the window form application.
it works when i change the base class from control to usercontrol.

anyone can help me, thanks.

```c
#pragma once

#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Drawing.dll>
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

namespace cc {
    public ref class Class1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Control
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.

    public:
        Class1()
        {
            this->SetStyle(ControlStyles::ResizeRedraw, true);
            this->SetStyle(ControlStyles::UserPaint, true);
            this->SetStyle(ControlStyles::AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        }


    protected:
        virtual void OnPaint(  PaintEventArgs^ e ) override
        {
            __super::OnPaint(e);
            System::Drawing::Rectangle rcRect = this->ClientRectangle;

            // Create a local version of the graphics object for the PictureBox.
            Graphics^ g = e->Graphics;

            // Draw a string on the PictureBox.
            g->DrawString("This is a diagonal line drawn on the control",
                gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial",10), System::Drawing::Brushes::Blue, Point(30,30));
            // Draw a line in the PictureBox.
            g->DrawLine(System::Drawing::Pens::Red, this->Left, this->Top,
                this->Right, this->Bottom);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Works fine when I try it.  Nothing wrong with the code.  Maybe something wrong with where you put it, hard to guess.